# Compare optical Sensitivity of two sensors

Tags: adc, sensitivity

I have two different sensors. Both have 16-bits ADC, both operate at Vdd = 3V, but their dynamic range is different. One has dynamic range of 50M:1 with gain range of x8 and the other has 500k:1 with gain range of x140. How do I find how much more sensitive one sensor is over the other?

Comment: Hello, lizard - We need some more information. It would be best if you could provide links to the datasheets of the sensors you are asking about. Your descriptions are hard to understand. If you can't do that, you need to tell us what the "gain range" means. It's clear that English isn't your strong point, so try to give us a better idea of what you mean.

Comment: I apologize I can not provide the datasheet of the device.  The output of the device can be gained by x1, x2, x4, or x8.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with the information you've presented, there is simply no way to know which is more sensitive. When you specify two different dynamic ranges as XXX:1, the 1 is the smallest input for each, but there is no way to tell what 1 is relative to the other. Sorry.

Comment: Do you have part numbers to each? Manufacturers?

Comment: I apologize but the parts not released yet.  Please ask what other info you may need which I can provide so you can help answer the question.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that are able to get the readings from each sensor and that they are operational.

You will need to find a way of controlling the light into the sensor in a controllable way.  This can be either through ND filters (ND = Neutral Density) a controlled aperture or through chopping.  A controlled aperture can be a lens with a controlled F/# 1, stop is typically 2x the amount of light.  A chopper can be a spinning disk with 1/2 or 1/4 of the disks covered/open and it needs to spin fast enough that the sensor cannot keep up, it sees the "average"

If you reduce the ratio of light by 1/2 and even better also by 1/4 and compare the readings, it will be obvious which one has the higher gain.

From the comment thread : "some more info Device A has 439counts/uW/cm2 and device B has 3 counts/uW.cm2. 22 μW/cm2 is the irradiance for White LED source"

439/3 => 146.33:1 increaased sensitivity.

Let's review what is happening.  The dynamic range is the ratio of the maximum signal to inherent noise of the sensor.  When you increase the sensitivity you are actually increasing the gain of the circuit this amplifies the gain of the maximum and also the noise.

Let's have a made up scenario to illustrate:
sensor X is low sensitivity and requires 2000 w/cm^2 at maximum.  If you increase the light the output saturates (also known as clipping).  the noise level equivalent to 4 w/cm^2.  the sensor is nicely calibrated so the the digital number is 2000 in the bright and 4 in the dark.

The DR = 2000/4 = 500:1

I increase the sensitivity by 100 X, that means that sensor will put out it's maximum of 2000 at 20 w/cm^2 and the noise level will be 4*100 = 400. The sensor with the higher sensitivity will by necessity have a worse DR in digital outputs 2000/400 = 5:1 in terms of light levels, 20/4 = 5:1.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.  Here is some more info Device A has 439counts/uW/cm2 and device B has 3 counts/uW.cm2.  22 μW/cm2 is the irradiance for White LED source.  Hope this helps

Comment: Device A is the more sensitive one.  IF you already have this data why are you asking the questions?  I think that you maybe english is not your first language?  On Stack exchange you say thank you by voting ...

Comment: i know that device A is sensitive than B but by how much? This is my first time on this site so I do not know how to vote yet.  I will find a what to vote.

Comment: The problem is that the designer informs that the device A is 10 times more sensitive than device B.  I am not sure how to calculate this.

Comment: I have done this using two polarizing filters. One is rotated with respect to the other to get a broad lighting range and both sensors are in the light path at the same time. Light through the filters is proportional to $$\cos ^{2}\phi $$ where $$ \phi $$ is the angle between the two polarizers angles of polarization.

Comment: I think you are mixing up *sensitivity* and *responsivity*. If we have 1 uW input and device A produces 439 counts output with 400 counts rms noise; while device B produces 3 counts output with 1 count rms noise, then device A has better responsivity, but device B has better sensitivity.

Comment: Nope. Sensitivity of a sensor is defined as the change in output of the sensor per unit change in the parameter being measured.  A higher gain = higher Sensitivity.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold it's measuring energy flow.  A photon counting detector is a different beast. and uW means microwatt, not micro wave ;)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I'm not the OP, and define "typical".  I've made billion of photodiodes that detect single photons. 0.5 uA/uW is just that particular mode of operation and probably companies making compatible devices.

Comment: @placeholder oh sorry, I'm not sure where the uW numbers came from.  Re: typical,  Well of course the sensitivity of a PD depends on the wavelength.  I do the NIR ~800nm where I get 0.6 A/W, so I guess my typical number is closer to 650nm red.  (only your spec sheet knows for sure.)  Have you serious done  single photons in a semiconductor?  SPAD's?  It's a subject I'm very interested in.  AFAIK there's only one place in the US selling them, several $k each.